# strucchange not reporting breakdates

Tags: r, time-series

This is my first time with strucchange so bear with me.  The problem I'm having seems to be that strucchange doesn't recognize my time series correctly but I can't figure out why and haven't found an answer on the boards that deals with this.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
require(strucchange)
# time series
nmreprosuccess <- c(0,0.50,NA,0.,NA,0.5,NA,0.50,0.375,0.53,0.846,0.44,1.0,0.285, 
                    0.75,1,0.4,0.916,1,0.769,0.357)
dat.ts <- ts(nmreprosuccess, frequency=1, start=c(1996,1))
str(dat.ts)
```

Time-Series [1:21] from 1996 to 2016: 0 0.5 NA 0 NA 0.5 NA 0.5 0.375 0.53 ...

To me this means that the time series looks OK to work with.

```
# obtain breakpoints
bp.NMSuccess <- breakpoints(dat.ts~1)
summary(bp.NMSuccess)
```

Which gives:

```
Optimal (m+1)-segment partition: 

 Call:
 breakpoints.formula(formula = dat.ts ~ 1)

 Breakpoints at observation number:

 m = 1     6              
 m = 2   3   7            
 m = 3   3           14 16
 m = 4   3   7       14 16
 m = 5   3   7 10    14 16
 m = 6   3   7 10 12 14 16
 m = 7   3 5 7 10 12 14 16

 Corresponding to breakdates:

 m = 1                     0.333333333333333                                                      
 m = 2   0.166666666666667                   0.388888888888889                                    
 m = 3   0.166666666666667                                                                        
 m = 4   0.166666666666667                   0.388888888888889                                    
 m = 5   0.166666666666667                   0.388888888888889 0.555555555555556                  
 m = 6   0.166666666666667                   0.388888888888889 0.555555555555556 0.666666666666667
 m = 7   0.166666666666667 0.277777777777778 0.388888888888889 0.555555555555556 0.666666666666667

 m = 1                                      
 m = 2                                      
 m = 3   0.777777777777778 0.888888888888889
 m = 4   0.777777777777778 0.888888888888889
 m = 5   0.777777777777778 0.888888888888889
 m = 6   0.777777777777778 0.888888888888889
 m = 7   0.777777777777778 0.888888888888889

 Fit:

 m   0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7      
 RSS  1.6986  1.1253  0.9733  0.8984  0.7984  0.7581  0.7248  0.7226
 BIC 14.3728 12.7421 15.9099 20.2490 23.9062 28.7555 33.7276 39.4522
```

Here's where I start having the problem.  Instead of reporting the actual breakdates it reports numbers which then makes it impossible to plot the break lines onto a graph because they're not at the breakdate (2002) but at 0.333.

```
plot.ts(dat.ts, main="Natural Mating")
lines(fitted(bp.NMSuccess, breaks = 1), col = 4, lwd = 1.5)
```

Nothing shows up for me in this graph (I think because it's so small for the scale of the graph).

In addition, when I try fixes that may possibly work around this problem,

```
fm1 <- lm(dat.ts ~ breakfactor(bp.NMSuccess, breaks = 1))
```

I get:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dat.ts ~ breakfactor(bp.NMSuccess,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'breakfactor(bp.NMSuccess, breaks = 1)')
```

I get errors because of the NA values in the data so the length of `dat.ts` is 21 and the length of `breakfactor(bp.NMSuccess, breaks = 1)` 18 (missing the 3 NAs).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions about how to use R code / error messages are generally off topic here. I think this should be on topic on [SO], so if you wait, we will try to migrate it there.

Comment: The problem are the NAs which need to be omitted for the regression but then ts() is not able to represent the time index anymore. You will have to work around this... let's wait until the question was migrated to SO and then I'll answer there.

Comment: @Achim Zeileis OK thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs because `breakpoints()` currently can only (a) cope with `NA`s by omitting them, and (b) cope with times/date through the `ts` class. This creates the conflict because when you omit internal `NA`s from a `ts` it loses its `ts` property and hence `breakpoints()` cannot infer the correct times.

The "obvious" way around this would be to use a time series class that can cope with this, namely `zoo`. However, I just never got round to fully integrate `zoo` support into `breakpoints()` because it would likely break some of the current behavior.

To cut a long story short: Your best choice at the moment is to do the book-keeping about the times yourself and not expect `breakpoints()` to do it for you. The additional work is not so huge. First, we create a time series with the response and the time vector and omit the `NA`s:

```
d <- na.omit(data.frame(success = nmreprosuccess, time = 1996:2016))
d
##    success time
## 1    0.000 1996
## 2    0.500 1997
## 4    0.000 1999
## 6    0.500 2001
## 8    0.500 2003
## 9    0.375 2004
## 10   0.530 2005
## 11   0.846 2006
## 12   0.440 2007
## 13   1.000 2008
## 14   0.285 2009
## 15   0.750 2010
## 16   1.000 2011
## 17   0.400 2012
## 18   0.916 2013
## 19   1.000 2014
## 20   0.769 2015
## 21   0.357 2016
```

Then we can estimate the breakpoint(s) and afterwards transform from the "number" of observations back to the time scale. Note that I'm setting the minimal segment size `h` explicitly here because the default of 15% is probably somewhat small for this short series. 4 is still small but possibly enough for estimating of a constant mean.

```
bp <- breakpoints(success ~ 1, data = d, h = 4)
bp
##   Optimal 2-segment partition: 
## 
## Call:
## breakpoints.formula(formula = success ~ 1, h = 4, data = d)
## 
## Breakpoints at observation number:
## 6 
## 
## Corresponding to breakdates:
## 0.3333333
```

We ignore the break "date" at 1/3 of the observations but simply map back to the original time scale:

```
d$time[bp$breakpoints]
## [1] 2004
```

To re-estimate the model with nicely formatted factor levels, we could do:

```
lab <- c(
  paste(d$time[c(1, bp$breakpoints)], collapse = "-"),
  paste(d$time[c(bp$breakpoints + 1, nrow(d))], collapse = "-")
)
d$seg <- breakfactor(bp, labels = lab)
lm(success ~ 0 + seg, data = d)
## Call:
## lm(formula = success ~ 0 + seg, data = d)
## 
## Coefficients:
## seg1996-2004  seg2005-2016  
##       0.3125        0.6911
```

Or for visualization:

```
plot(success ~ time, data = d, type = "b")
lines(fitted(bp) ~ time, data = d, col = 4, lwd = 2)
abline(v = d$time[bp$breakpoints], lty = 2)
```

[image: success series with breaks]

One final remark: For such short time series where just a simple shift in the mean is needed, one could also consider conditional inference (aka permutation tests) rather than the asymptotic inference employed in `strucchange`. The `coin` package provides the `maxstat_test()` function exactly for this purpose (= short series where a single shift in the mean is tested).

```
library("coin")
maxstat_test(success ~ time, data = d, dist = approximate(99999))
##  Approximative Generalized Maximally Selected Statistics
## 
## data:  success by time
## maxT = 2.3953, p-value = 0.09382
## alternative hypothesis: two.sided
## sample estimates:
##   "best" cutpoint: <= 2004
```

This finds the same breakpoint and provides a permutation test p-value. If however, one has more data and needs multiple breakpoints and/or further regression coefficients, then `strucchange` would be needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly and allows me to analyze further data I have from this dataset with longer ts and more breakpoints!